# Nestjs TypeORM BasicEntity not respecting naming convention

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to use the `SnakeNamingConvention` in my `nest` and `TypeORM` project but am getting a query error when I attempt to use the `BaseEntity.#save` method on my custom entity. Here are relevant pieces of code:

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { SnakeNamingStrategy } from 'typeorm-naming-strategies'

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({ namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy() }),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({ autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gql' }),
    UserModule,
  ],
})
```

**users.entity.ts**

```js
@ObjectType()
@Entity('user')
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string

  @Field()
  @Column({ length: 20, nullable: false })
  firstName: string

  @Field()
  @Column({ length: 25, nullable: false })
  lastName: string
}
```

**users.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  create(createUserInput: CreateUserServiceInput) {
    return User.create(createUserInput).save()
  }
}
```

My error is:

> column "firstName" of relation "user" does not exist